# In solr how to find no of occurrences of searched words in each document

Tags: solr

I want to find out how many times the searched keyword repeated in each document. For Ex: search word: pharmacy related. This word may be repeated n no of times in all MATCHED documents, how to find out the COUNT per document? Please suggest me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with Solr's [functions](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#Relevance_Functions):

```
termfreq(text,'pharmacy related')
```

The only condition for that is you need to index this field correctly! In case when you need to return count of phrases rather than single words, I would use [ShingleFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ShingleFilterFactory)

Comment: Hi thank u very much, can u plz tell me how to call this function from java.. I tried looking at api & searched for examples also but i didn't get. Also if i'm searching across all fields then should i need to use ShingleFilterFactory on all fields?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using pySolr and similar tools. However in regular HTTP call I would just use: "fl=count_1:termfreq(text,'pharmacy related')". I know to little about your problem to advise whether you should use ShingleFilterFactory on all of your fields. This is one option, another would be to have a copy of all your fields with that filter or have 1 fields with where you would copy in content form field you're interested and apply filter there (No one said you need to search a run function on the same field)

Comment: Hi thank u very much, i got it. One more thing is i want to consider termfreq as major factor while solr returning results. How to do that? i didnt get it. I dont want to boost some fields whatever user searches in whichever field i want to boost results based on no. of occurences inside a document..

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't understand what you're after.